# Can a data driven xUnit test run all instances of the test (i.e for each set of data) in parallel?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, xunit, xunit.net

As far as I can tell for the xUnit .net framework to run tests in parallel they must be in different test classes at a minimum, they must also be in separate test collections.

Is there no way to run a single data driven test with multiple data input all in parallel?

for example:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(3)]
[InlineData(5)]
[InlineData(6)]
public void MyFirstTheory(int value)
{
    Assert.True(IsOdd(value));
}

bool IsOdd(int value)
{
    return value % 2 == 1;
}
```

This will run the test three times with the different data, but it will run in serial, I want the three tests to run in parallel.

Comment: Nope (AFAIK), you may open an issue for that "case" (https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/)

Comment: Hi, did u find the answer, or did u log a issue?

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback.  No real answer yet, I have raised https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/648 as you suggested. A colleague did suggest using http://www.ncrunch.net/, Which I tried and it looked like it was running the data driven test instances in parallel (they all showed as running at the same time) however when I experimented using different wait times in the tests it seemed they weren't running in parallel.  I'm pretty sure that I had NCrunch setup correctly, but there is a chance that is works and I just had the config wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments in https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/648 this is not possible. And won't be due to xunit .net design decisions.